# Send mail using email from user database in django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms

In Django how can i send email to user by importing email from user database.

from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class PostCreateView(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):

```
model = Post
form_class = AdsForm

def form_valid(self, form):
    
    email = User.email # try to import email from user model database.

    subject = 'Thanks for adding your trip'
    message = f'Hi {email}, thank you for Adding your Trip .'
    email_from = 'xyz@gmail.com'
    recipient_list = [email]
   
  
    send_mail(subject, message, email_from, recipient_list, fail_silently=False)
    form.instance.author = self.request.user
    return super().form_valid(form)
```

In this form i tried to send email to the user that adding trip, the email i tried to pickup from User database. And i get this error while sending the mail.

[image]

Help would be appreciated as Iam beginner to Django and programming.

Comment: You can access the email field for the current user  with `self.request.user.email`

Answer (score 1):

If you want user email(who send the request now) you should use:

```
self.request.user.email
```

after that you can use it as valid email